# Array with multiple numerical ranges

Tags: php

If I have multiple numerical ranges I need to put into an array (i.e. `1-14` and `21-30`), how would I do this?

PHP has range(), but it only handles one range:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: So use two `range()` one `array_merge()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$alphas = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'));
```

refer
[Way to get all alphabetic chars in an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431912/way-to-get-all-alphabetic-chars-in-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution -

```
$array = array_merge(range(1, 14), range(21, 30));
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/336469)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
<?php
$number = range(0,14);
$num= range(21,30);
$array = array_merge($number , $num );
print_r ($array );
?>
```

Here is [Demo](http://codepad.org/CHGsmO2V)

For your reference [Reference Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_range.asp)