# From base 10 to base 26 only with letters so that 26 will be aa

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the CONV function in Mysql:

```
mysql> CONV(26,10,26)
      -> 10
```

But I want something like this:

```
mysql> CONV_LETTERS(26,10,26)
      -> aa
```

**How can I convert in MySQL from base 10 to base 26, but only use letters so that number 26 will become aa?**

UPDATE

I got so far:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `base10_to_base26_letters`(IN `nr` BIGINT)
BEGIN

SET @letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
select SUBSTRING(@letters,`nr`+1,1);

END//
```

UPDATE 2

Trying to convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836519/206609) php function to MySQL procedure.

The PHP function:

```
function generateAlphabet($na) {
    $sa = "";
    while ($na >= 0) {
        $sa = chr($na % 26 + 65) . $sa;
        $na = floor($na / 26) - 1;
    }
    return $sa;
}
```

My MySQL procedure so far:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `base10_to_base26_letters`(IN `nr` BIGINT)
BEGIN

SET @n=`nr`,@letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',@r='';
while @n>=0 do
set @n=@n/26-1,@r=concat(SUBSTRING(@letters,@n%26,1),@r);
end while;
select @r;

END//
```

Why I only get z for any number I tried?

Comment: The question is unclear. Decimal 26 is 10 in base 26 - you can't change it, that's just math. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik I think OP wants excel style column-numbering/indexing.

Comment: I want to convert a number like '1000' base 10 from database to 'alm' base 26 only with letters to use it in proper naming convention in my application.

Comment: If you want to use "a" as 0, then 26 would have to be "ba", "aa" will is the same as "a", and "aaa".

Comment: My counting: 0:a,1:b,2:c,3:d,4:e,5:f,6:g,7:h,8:i,9:j,10:k,11:l,12:m,13:n,14:o,15:p,16:q,17:r,18:s,19:t,20:u,21:v,22:w,23:x,24:y,25:z,26:aa

Comment: That's just not how number bases work, I'm afraid.

Comment: are you playing with cryptographer?  Number system doesn't works that way.  Do you know that ZERO (0) is a special number in math. There is a reason why mathematician use ZERO for century.

Comment: So the correct mapping for base10 to base 26  =  0:0,  1:a , 2:b..... 26:z  , 27:10. 
Don't underestimate and omit zero.

Comment: I don't wanna do math with it, is just for some proper naming conventions.

Comment: 'aaa' is like '000'.  You want 'ba'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stored function converts a single int to base26:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `base10to26`;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE FUNCTION `base10to26`(`theNumber` INT(11) UNSIGNED) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20) READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE colTxt VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE value  INT(11);
    SET colTxt = '';

    REPEAT
        SET value  = theNumber % 26;
        IF value = 0 THEN SET value = 26; END IF;
        SET theNumber = (theNumber - value) / 26;
        SET colTxt = CONCAT(CHAR(value+64), colTxt);
    UNTIL theNumber = 0 END REPEAT;

    RETURN colTxt;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `IF value = 0 THEN value = 26; END IF;` should be `IF SET value = 0 THEN value = 26; END IF;` Otherwise you get an error. But what I want is a random number in base 10 like 23565 to be converted to base 26 counting only with letters. Instead of `colNum` and `rowNum` should be only something like `Num`

Comment: @Alqin: the bug you pointed out is fixed and the code is updated to convert a single number to base26

Answer (score 3):

We are doing this in PHP:

```
private function numToB26($num)
{
    /* $num++; // Uncomment to use "Excel"-mapping, e.g. 1=A instead of 0=A */
    do {
        $val = ($num % 26) ?: 26;
        $num = ($num - $val) / 26;
        $b26 = chr($val + 64).($b26 ?: '');
    } while (0 < $num);
    return $b26;
}
```

Comment: I was hopping for a  MySQL solution. There are a couple of findings over the internet for PHP but none for MySQL.

Comment: in PHP you have a built-in function `base_convert` that will do that.